# Using ADO.NET Entity Framework with MySql Data Provider

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, mariadb, ado.net, mysql-connector

I'm going to start an ASP.NET Web Application project that uses the MySql database. I also need to create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

I know I need to install "MySql for Visual Studio Tool" and "MySql Connector/NET".

1. I have installed VS2019 Community.
2. I installed MySql Connector/NET 8.0.28.
3. I have installed MySql for Visual Studio Tool 1.2.10.
4. I open VS2019. I am successfully connecting to the remote mysql
   database from Server Explorer > Data Connections.
5. I created a new MVC Web Application(4.5.2 / 4.6.1 / 4.7.2).
6. I have installed MySql.Data.EntityFramework package.
7. In the last step of the ADO.NET Entity Data Model installation
   wizard (Choose Your Data Connection), the installer suddenly closes.

I can share the database connection information that I will connect to via message. I also write the database properties below.
I couldn't find which versions would work in harmony. Can you try this on your own machine and let me know after you make sure it works? I need your support My Stack Family.

MySql Database information:

- Server: localhost via TCP/IP
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
- Server version: 10.6.9-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
- Protocol version: 10
- User: u1307312_user1A6@localhost
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

---

- Microsoft-IIS/10.0
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.33
- PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
- PHP version: 7.4.33

The result of the query `show variables like '%char%'` :

- character_set_client: utf8mb4
- character_set_connection: utf8mb4
- character_set_database: utf8mb4
- character_set_filesystem: binary
- character_set_results: utf8mb4
- character_set_server: utf8mb4
- character_set_system: utf8mb3
- character_sets_dir: C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.6\share\charsets\

Comment: I created a video recording for you. You can check out my actions here. https://www.veed.io/view/361a18d3-67f4-4420-8642-a9809d92a937?panel=share

Comment: I still haven't found a solution. how can i solve this problem?
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107259